# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 2 column 14 of the JSON data with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to get the similar structure with http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094. I replaced tree.json with my json data and modified the code a bit but it does not seem to work.

structure.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.name {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.about {
  fill: #777;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 0, right: 320, bottom: 0, left: 0},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .separation(function(a, b) { return a.parent === b.parent ? 1 : .5; })
    .children(function(d) { return d.parents; })
    .size([height, width]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("tree.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var nodes = tree.nodes(json);

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", elbow);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  node.append("text")
      .attr("class", "name")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .text(function(d) { return d.vision; });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("class", "name")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .text(function(d) { return d.actor; });

/*  node.append("text")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", 8)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("class", "about lifespan")
      .text(function(d) { return d.born + "–" + d.died; });*/

/*  node.append("text")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", 8)
      .attr("dy", "1.86em")
      .attr("class", "about location")
      .text(function(d) { return d.location; });*/
});

function elbow(d, i) {
  return "M" + d.source.y + "," + d.source.x
       + "H" + d.target.y + "V" + d.target.x
       + (d.target.children ? "" : "h" + margin.right);
}

</script>
```

tree.json

```
{
  "value": "{\"vision\":[\"For Commuters who Spend hell lot of time in traffic  is a Traditional Commuting solution that Tracking enabled mobile App unlike Sharing the rides our product Car pooling \",\"For Commuters who Spend hell lot of time in traffic  is a Traditional Commuting solution that Tracking enabled mobile App unlike Sharing the rides our product Car pooling \"],\"actors\":[\"Commuters\",\"Government\"]}"
}
```

Comment: Paste your JSON into http://jsonlint.com

Comment: I did and it shows that it's a valid json

Comment: What's posted above ("tree.json") isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @user2900150 try again. jsonlint.com shows your error.

Comment: I just updated the json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe your JSON:

```
{
    "value": "{"vision":["For Commuters ... "]}"
}
```

Your `value` of "value" is in string. This is a JSON object and should not be declared as a string. Here is the right format (see I removed the quotes):

```
{
    "value": {"vision":["For Commuters ... "]}
}
```

***From comments I read*** that when you pasted your JSON in `jsonlint` you got that its a valid JSON. That's because `jsonlint` thought that you wrote something like this:

```
{
    "value": "another_value"
}
```

Since your JSON object was in quotes, `jsonlint` took it as a literal string.

PS: In your heading you yourself mentioned that the error is in line2, column 14. Well count what is in line 2 and column 14 - its your `"` character which you needed to remove.